# Consume GCS files based on pattern from Flink

Tags: apache-flink, google-cloud-dataproc

Since Flink supports the Hadoop FileSystem abstraction, and there's a [GCS connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop) - library that implements it on top of Google Cloud Storage.

How do I create a Flink file source using the code in this repo?

Comment: Related but a sink https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860988/flink-checkpoints-to-google-cloud-storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you need to:

1. [Install and configure](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/install-storage-connector) GCS connector on your Flink cluster.
2. Add Hadoop and Flink dependencies (including [HDFS connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/filesystem_sink.html#hdfs-connector)) to your project:

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
       <artifactId>flink-scala_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>${flink.version}</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
       <artifactId>flink-connector-filesystem_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>${flink.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
       <artifactId>flink-hadoop-compatibility_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>${flink.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
       <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
       <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
       <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
       <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. [Use it](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/hadoop_compatibility.html#using-hadoop-inputformats) to create data source with GCS path:

   ```java
   import org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet;
   import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
   import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
   import org.apache.flink.hadoopcompatibility.HadoopInputs;
   import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
   import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
   import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;

   ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

   DataSet<Tuple2<LongWritable, Text>> input =
       env.createInput(
           HadoopInputs.readHadoopFile(
               new TextInputFormat(), LongWritable.class, Text.class, "gs://bucket/path/some*pattern/"));
   ```

Comment: The above is not enough; HadoopInputs doesn't exist there. It's in the compat lib.

Also, can I get a stream from the files, like with `env.readFiles`?

Comment: Also, what is LongWritable and Text? I have newline JSON in the files I'm trying to read; how would I configure that?

Comment: Also, LongWritable doesn't exist anywhere that IntelliJ can find.

Comment: Thanks for fixing dependencies!
`LongWriter` is a Hadoop class from [`hadoop-common` dependency](https://search.maven.org/search?q=c:LongWritable%20AND%20g:org.apache.hadoop%20AND%20a:hadoop-common), it should be included with Flink.

Comment: I don't think that you can use `env.readFile(...)` for this, because it accepts Flink's `FileInputFormat` which is different from Hadoop's `TextInputFormat`.

Comment: So if I have a nl-json file, what do I get out? I haven't been able to make the above compile. E.g. what is the long in the above code - a position? But there are many filees and I just want a subset of them, and also, Flink should handle the position it's read. Also, what is Text and how do I turn it into a string? Also, there are multiple filese in GCS, not just one; so I want a DataStream<string> (json lines) out of it?

Comment: Long is [a line number](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/dead9b4049484c31e0608956e53a9ef07a45819d/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TextInputFormat.java#L32) in the text file. This is how [`readInputFile` works](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/b62db93bf63cb3bb34dd03d611a779d9e3fc61ac/flink-connectors/flink-hadoop-compatibility/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/hadoopcompatibility/HadoopInputs.java#L35) in Flink. You can ignore line number and process only lines, by converting them to JSON.

Comment: If these files contain multi-line JSON objects (instead of single-line JSON objects), then you need to define new `InputFormat` to parse them, here is an [example](https://github.com/Pivotal-Field-Engineering/pmr-common/blob/master/PivotalMRCommon/src/main/java/com/gopivotal/mapreduce/lib/input/JsonInputFormat.java) of such `InputFormat`.

Comment: I would advise you to create a new question and ask how to read JSON file from [HCFS](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HCFS) (which includes HDFS, GCS, S3, etc) file system in Flink and add snippet of file content. It will be easier to answer it this way.

Comment: Ok, but we still need to find out the exact references needed for this to work as well as the imports as some of the class names here are overloaded...

Comment: Sure, updated answer with all necessary dependencies and imports.

Comment: On the line `<groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-hadoop-compatibility_2.11</artifactId>
...
    <scope>provided</scope>` I think it should not be provided, since 1.8 dropped Hadoop libs out of the box, and I think the same goes for the other hadoopy stuff

Comment: Removed `provided` from Flink's Hadoop dependencies, but left it for Hadoop itself - Flink should have it on classpath.

Comment: I think it was removed in 1.8 https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/release-notes/flink-1.8.html#maven-dependencies — also, if you run without adding it manually, the GCS filesystem doesn't work

Comment: Dataproc doesn't support Flink 1.8 yet, and when it will it will include Hadoop jars - just as it was before Flink 1.8. Dataproc builds packages from source and doesn't rely on binary distributions.