# Read JSON-newline file with HCFS

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink, google-cloud-dataproc

How can I make the Flink HCFS connector read from Google Cloud Storage with a pattern like `**/*S0.json`, where the files contain newline delimited JSON data?

The files contain contents like

```
{"message": "Hello world", "timestamp": 1556655155}
{"message": "Goodbye world", "timestamp": 1556655170}
```

In the GCS UI, it looks like this:

[image: Sample files]

Follow up from [Consume GCS files based on pattern from Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612471/consume-gcs-files-based-on-pattern-from-flink/55617019)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55617019/3227693) JSON file from HCFS as a plain text you can [map](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/dataset_transformations.html#map) it to `JSONObject` using [custom mapper](https://github.com/ottogroup/flink-operator-library/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ottogroup/bi/streaming/operator/json/converter/StringToJsonObject.java):

```java
import org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONObject;

DataSet<JSONObject> jsonInput = 
    input
        .map(record -> record.f1.toString())
        .map(StringToJsonObject::new);
```

`JSONObject` mapper code based on example linked above:

```java
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONObject;

public class StringToJsonObject implements MapFunction<String, JSONObject> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4573928723585302447L;

    public JSONObject map(String content) throws Exception {
        return new JSONObject(content);
    }
}
```

If necessary you can map `String` to POJO instead of generic `JSONObject` using mapper similar to [this one](https://github.com/okkam-it/flink-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/it/okkam/flink/json/JsonStringToPojo.java).

Comment: Ok, but what's the int? Who decides the int? And if I want to write it back? Do I use the same int?

Comment: Also, I'd like a DataStream, not a DataSet. For text files, you can specify a glob pattern; is there something similar for this? Or is Hadoop compat only for batch runs?

Comment: `f0` `int` value is a line number in the file, you don't need to write it back.